# How to solve a problem of set theory

Tags: combinatorics

I don't know the formula to use in a problem: 
If a group of 400 persons, 250 persons speaks English, 200 speaks French, so the number of persons speaking both the languages is ?

And the answer is 80

Comment: If English and French are the only languages involved, and everyone in the group speaks at least one of them, the number speaking both English and French is $50$, not $80$. $200+250=450$, so $50$ people have been counted twice when we simply add the numbers of French and English speakers, and therefore $50$ must speak both languages.

Comment: $\;80\;$ is wrong, I think.

Comment: You might have forgotten to mention the number of people who speak at least one of those languages, or perhaps the number of people who speak neither french nor english.  With the given numbers, if $370$ people speak at least one of french or english (or equivalently $30$ people out of the $400$ speak neither french nor english), then the answer of $80$ would be correct.  Regardless, as mentioned already, inclusion-exclusion is the correct approach.  $|F\cup E|=|F|+|E|-|F\cap E|$

Comment: Don't use a formula.  Use common sense. 250 people speak english, 200 speak french.  The number of people who speak English plus the number of people who speak French is 450.  450 is more than the number of people so there most be some overlap.  There is at least 50 overlap.  It's *from* this common sense that we get the formula: $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$  So we have $200 \ge |English \cup french| = |french| + |english| - |both-french -and-english|$

Comment: If the answer is 80 then there are 30 people who speak neither.  30 speak neither + 200 speak french + 250 speak English - 80 speak both = 200 total.

Comment: 80 isn't wrong.  The answer is AT LEAST 50 speak both.  If more than 50 speak both than some must speak *neither* french nor english.  30 people don't speak either language.

Comment: There isn't enough information to get what the answer is.  You can conclude the answer is between 50 and 200.  It is 50 if everybody speaks either french or english.  It is 200 if everybody who speaks french also speaks english, 150 speak neither and nobody speaks only French.

Comment: @Fleablood It seems clear, at least to me, that from the wording of the problem a reasonable assumption is that every person speaks at least one of the languages., and thus *the* answer is $\;50\;$ . Also, the asker writes about **the answer**, not *an* answer.

Comment: I don't see that is at all a reasonable assumption.  Give the question as stated I'd conclude "the answer" is "at least 50".  I do concede, that there is no possible way with the information given to reach the answer 80.  I would take given that the answer is 80 as a stepping off point to "what can we then conclude" in which we can conclude there are 30 people that speak neither.  In fact I somehow missed the comment that the answer was 80 when I wrote my first comment "there is at least 50 overlap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;F,E\;$ be the set of people that speaks french (respecitvely, english), then use the formula:

$$|F\cup E|=|F|+|E|-|F\cap E|$$

Comment: But the answer is 80 and by your given formula its gives answer 50.

Comment: @Panchalheta With the given information the answer cannot be $\;80\;$ , and I see Brian already wrote this in the comments. Either you miscopied some data or whoever says the answer is $\;80\;$ is wrong.

Comment: Of, course the answer can be 80d  The answer can be anything between 50 and 200.  $250 \le |F \cup E| \le 400$. As it turns out $|F \cup E| = 370$. Reapplying this formula we can conclude the number of people who speak neither french nor english is 30.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you. But then neither 80 nor any other number is **the** answer, but one possible answer if at all. I'm assuming that in this basic problem $\;|F\cup E|=400\;$ , meaning: any person in the problem speaks either french or english or both.

Comment: It's very clear from the information given that we can not conclude a single answer.  I don't see anything in the stating of the problem that leads us to assume $|F \cup E| = 400$.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the answer further Let U = everyone

F = people who speak french

E = people who speak English

$F \cup E$ = people who speak French *or* English

$F \cap E$ = people who speak French *and* English

$(F \cup E)^c$ = people who speak *neither* French nor English.

There are two formulas: $|U| = |A^c| + |A|$

and $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$.

We can combine these to get $|U| = |(A \cup B)^c| + |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$.

So $|U| = |(E \cup F)^c| + |F| + |E| - |E \cap F|$

So $200 = |(E \cup F)^c| + 200 + 250 - |E \cap F|$

So $|E \cap F| = 50 + |(E \cup F)^c|$

So the number of people who speak both French and English is 50 more than the number who speak neither.